# Copying table data from table#1 to table#2 based on value of column in table#1

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-insert

```
Table#1: workorders
 columns:
 dept_name,
 dept_code,
 validity_work_order
 work_order_no //primary key

Table#2: History_workorders
 columns:
 dept_name,
 dept_code,
 validity_work_order
 work_order_no //primary key
```

My requirement is to copy all records from Table#1 to Table#2 whose validity has expired and then delete them from Table#1.
I am using Oracle 10g R2 Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO  History_workorders SELECT * FROM workorders WHERE validity_work_order < sysdate

Delete from workorders where work_order_no in(select work_order_no  from History_workorders);
```

I hope you have put complete requirement here.
above code may need some changes based on your needs.

Comment: workorder expires if validity_work_order<Systemdate. so will only above queris serve the purpose?

Comment: Keep coding ..and if you find the solution as per your needs.mark it as an answer and rate me

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into History_workorders  
select * from workorders 
where validity_work_order='Expired';
delete from workorder where  validity_work_order='Expired';
```